# Flutter/Dart - Dynamic font size to fit Card

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create some ocassion cards inside a pageview and was wondering if there was a way to make my fontsize dynamic to avoid pixel overflow. Here is a screenshot of a card that works fine:

[image]

But when I add an occasion that has more characters...

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class Category {
String name;
IconData icon;
Widget route;
Category(this.name, this.icon, this.route);
}

class CalendarEvents {
  String title;
  String date;

  CalendarEvents(this.title, this.date);
}

class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
  List<Category> _categories = [
    Category('My History', Icons.history, MyHistory()),
    Category('Dates to Remember', Icons.event_note, DatesToRemember()),
    Category('Terms and Conditions', Icons.assignment, TermsandConditions()),
    Category('Privacy Notice', Icons.security, PrivacyNotice()),
    Category('Rate us' , Icons.stars, RateUs()),
    Category('Send us Feedback' , Icons.feedback, GiveUsFeedback())
  ];



  DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');


  List<CalendarEvents> _events = [
    CalendarEvents('Christmas Day', "25/12/2020"),
    CalendarEvents('New Years Eve', "31/12/2020"),
    CalendarEvents('New Years Day',"01/01/2021"),
    CalendarEvents('Valentines Day', "14/02/2021"),
    CalendarEvents('A very long occasion that needs to be resized','01/01/2021')
  ];

  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        children: [
      Container(
        child: SizedBox(
        height: 75, // card height
          child: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: _events.length,
            controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5),
            onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
            itemBuilder: (_, i) {
              return Transform.scale(
                scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.5,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(formatter.parse(_events[i].date).day.toString()),
                      Text(DateFormat.MMMM().format(formatter.parse(_events[i].date)).toString()),
                      Text(
                        _events[i].title,
                        style: AppBarTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
//          SizedBox(height: 100.0,),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(_categories[index].icon, color: Colors.black,),
                      title: Text(_categories[index].name),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _categories[index].route)),
                    ),
                    Divider(), //                  
                  ],
                );
              }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It would be useful to resize the font depending on the length of occasion. If this is possible, what would be the best way of achieving these results? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want control over the fontsize even after resized, you should use https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text package like @Abhishek mentioned

If you just want the text to resize freely, you can use FittedBox and wrap it around Text widget, like this:

```
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  child: Text()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text package like

```
title: Text(_categories[index].name),
```

instead of this

```
title: AutoSizeText(
  _categories[index].name,
  minFontSize: 10,
  stepGranularity: 10,
  maxLines: 4,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, i've implemented the proposed solution, but still get bottom overflow by 1 pixel?

Comment: use `isThreeLine: true,` in listTile

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit confused, it isn't the list tile that needs altering, it's the card elements above that? Would altering the below list tiles resolve my card issue above that? thanks

Comment: so make card responsive or give fixed height and width